# JavaScript form validation issue - submit has to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

JavaScript code of validation- https://freedigitalphotos.net/images/js/judd-validate.js

We have some new forms on our website which have client side JavaScript validation.

The validation is triggered when the user "defocuses" from the form fields. The validation is a combination of AJAX (checking database for valid user names etc) and JavaScript (checking fields not blank, or contain expected data).

The user has to click the form submit button twice to send the form. It seems that the first click is triggering the field validation but not submitting the form. Clicking for a second time successfully completes the form.

Go to- https://freedigitalphotos.net/images/recover_password.php
Type arifkpi@gmail.com in the email field, and then immediately hit submit. Again, notice that the first click merely validates the input, using AJAX it is checking the email address is in the database. A second click is required.

I want to fix this, so everything will work with a single click.

Comment: Works for me: Chrome 36.0.1985.125 - perhaps your ajax request is taking longer to respond? Open up your console and watch the network activity when you fill out your form and submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling Ajax validations on `focustout` event, you can call it on `click` of your button and if Ajax returns true result then `submit` form programatically. Refer few sample code lines:

Html Part:

```
<form method="post" id="registration_form" name="registration_form" action="register.php">
  EmailId: <input type="text" id="email_id" name="email_id">
  <label class="error" for="username" id="globalErrorUsername"></label>
  Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  <label class="error" id="globalErrorEmail"></label>
  <button type="button" id="register_btn" name="register_btn">Register</button>
</form>
```

Js Part:

```
$("#register_btn").click(function() {
    //.valid function is useful when you are using jquery Validate library for other field validation
    if ($('#registration_form').valid()) {
        var email_id = $('#registration_form').find('#email_id').val(),
            username = $('#registration_form').find('#username').val();
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#globalErrorUsername').html('');
                $('#globalErrorEmail').html('');
             }, //Show spinner
            complete: function() {  },
            type : 'post',
            url : 'check-user-existence.php',
            dataType :'json',
            data : 'email_id=' + email_id + '&username=' + username,
            success:function(response) {
                if(response.success == 1) {
                    //submit the form here
                    $("#registration_form").submit();
                } else if (response.error == 1) {
                    if(response.details.username != undefined) {
                        $('#globalErrorUsername').show();
                        $('#globalErrorUsername').html(response.details.username);
                    }
                    if(response.details.email_id != undefined) {
                        $('#globalErrorEmail').show();
                        $('#globalErrorEmail').html(response.details.email_id);
                        $('#email_id').focus();
                    } else {
                        $('#username').focus();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```